# (labelImg-master) "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml' even though lxml is installed (Windows 10)

Tags: python, windows, powershell, path, lxml

I was recently attempting to download labelImg-master through their instructions here (https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg). It was my first ever install using powershell and it didn't work and was giving me pyrcc5 problems, but I played around and it worked. However, after the first use, the program never opened again and gave me this error instead.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kevin\onedrive\documents\project\labelImg-master\labelImg-master\labelImg.py", line 41, in <module>
    from libs.labelFile import LabelFile, LabelFileError, LabelFileFormat
  File "C:\Users\kevin\onedrive\documents\project\labelImg-master\labelImg-master\libs\labelFile.py", line 10, in <module>
    from libs.pascal_voc_io import PascalVocWriter
  File "C:\Users\kevin\onedrive\documents\project\labelImg-master\labelImg-master\libs\pascal_voc_io.py", line 6, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'
```

I am assuming this is a path variable because one week ago, I deleted the main default path on accident. Now everything is messed up and my downloads even redirect to this Project folder.
Some more info:
Pip list shows that:

```
PS C:\Users\kevin\onedrive\documents\project\labelImg-master\labelImg-master> pip list
Package          Version
---------------- ------------
beautifulsoup4   4.9.3
certifi          2020.12.5
chardet          4.0.0
click            7.1.2
idna             2.10
lxml             4.6.2
pip              21.0.1
pyqt5-plugins    5.15.2.2.0.1
PyQt5-Qt         5.15.2
PyQt5-sip        12.8.1
pyqt5-tools      5.15.2.3.0.2
python-dotenv    0.15.0
qt5-applications 5.15.2.2.1
qt5-tools        5.15.2.1.0.1
requests         2.25.1
soupsieve        2.1
urllib3          1.26.2
```

Additionally, when finding the path for lxml, I added that directory into windows path variables.

```
Uninstalling lxml-4.6.2:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\kevin\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages\lxml-4.6.2.dist-info\*
    c:\users\kevin\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages\lxml\*
Proceed (y/n)?
```

(I added the above to path directories).

I would like to simply just start over again, but I do not believe I can reset my computer to what it was a week ago. Does anyone know what I should do?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything. Just execute the command:

```
conda activate C:\Users\[Your_Username]\anaconda3
```

And then Open your python file like What I do

**Note**

If you want to see this `C:\Users\[Your_Username]\anaconda3` type

```
conda info --envs
```